# Need advice regarding Node.js and WordPress integration

Tags: wordpress, node.js

got a Node.js web app (bound to http://my.example.com) and an official app's website (http://example.com) that is on WordPress.

The WordPress site is supposed to handle all the users' administration functions i.e. registration, buying app subscription, affiliate tracking etc.. I use it because it is faster for me now to stick with WordPress rather than develop all this stuff myself. So...

The problem I'm facing now is accessing users' credentials stored in WordPress upon logging in to the app.
My guess is that on getting a login post request from the app, I should fetch the user's data from the WordPress utilizing it's RPC api or query MySQL (don't know what is better yet). If the user exists and the password is correct, the user accesses the app, and if this is a new user, a new record is created in the app's database (MongoDB).

I would like to know are there any better solutions to this problem? I'm concerned about the security of this solution. Is it safe to solve a problem this way? What are the possible pitfalls with it?

Thanks for any reply)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO

> I should fetch the user's data from the WordPress utilizing it's RPC api or query MySQL (don't know what is better yet).

MySQL. AFAIK, WP RPC doesn't support `addUser` (see below)

> If the user exists and the password is correct, the user accesses the app, and if this is a new user, a new record is created in the app's database (MongoDB).

Here's the problem, now you have 2 user database. It'll be better if you add that new user to WP database, so the new user coming from the app should already have the account in the blog.

> I would like to know are there any better solutions to this problem?

Split up the user database so it stands on its own. Like StackOverflow and StackExchange family.

> I'm concerned about the security of this solution. Is it safe to solve a problem this way? What are the possible pitfalls with it?

Yes. Use a secure connection between node and MySQL if they don't sit on the same box or local network. Use different MySQL user for each app with proper access.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @soemarko.

> Here's the problem, now you have 2 user database.
> It'll be better if you add that new user to WP database,
> so the new user coming from the app should already have the account in the blog.

Users won't be able to register from the app. They will be coming only from the WordPress site. Thus the app's database will store only the users' settings. Does it change anything?

Comment: Better. A minor UX gripe though. you'll need to login right after signing up. Although you can just shared the session through cookie to solve it. Good luck.